# responsive slick carrousel issues

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I have a responsive jQuery Slick carousel with two issues. The first issue is the breadcrumbs disappear when the screen size is 600px or smaller. I do not want them to disappear.

The second issue is the carousel is aligned to the left at screen sizes of 1200px or larger. I need the carousel centered. Unfortunately, because I am using a plugin, I can not provide all of the code here, but I have provided all of the relevant code that I have.

Any solutions or guidance to either of the two issues would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      dots: true,
      speed: 300,
      infinite: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 5000,
      autoplay: true,
      responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 3000,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 767,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
      }
    }

  ]
    });
  });
```

```css
.wrapper{
    padding: 70px 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
  }
  .slide_container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 650px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
  }
 .slick-dots {
   margin: 0 auto;
   justify-content: center !important;
   rotate: 270deg;
   width: 10px;
   background-color: aquamarine;
  }
  .slick-active::marker {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .slick-track {
   position: right;
  }

  .slick-slide {
    height: 135px !important;
    max-width: 220px;;
  }

  #slick-slide-control00 {
    display: none;
  }#slick-slide-control01 {
    display: none;
  }
  #slick-slide-control02 {
    display: none;
  }
  #slick-slide-control03 {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .my-slider{
    padding: 0 70px;
    
  }
  .slick-initialized .slick-slide{
    background-color: #b32532;
    color: rgb(176, 180, 190);
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/media.css">


    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="bg">
        
        
        <div class="slide_container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="my-slider">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!---->
    </div>
            

    <!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="effects/main.js" defer></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: I have read How to Ask. @isherwood can you please tell me what part of my question needs adjustment? Im not sure what is causing the issues in my code, so it is hard for me to be any more specific in my questioning.

Comment: in your example the breadcrumbs don't disappear below 600px. as for alignment, can't you place the carousel inside a container and center the container?

Comment: I specifically suggested that your revise your _title_. Did you read the title section on that page? Yours doesn't meet standards. It's vague and not a question.

Comment: To center it in JS script add: centerMode: true, 
The CSS .slide_container seems to be set up improperly (justify content right?). 
And CSS .slick-initialized .slick-slide = it's not active on the HTML page but it looks like its the original code for the NPM plugin setup. 
It might be easier to just rebuild/reinstall it, or attain a centered slick slider example from elsewhere (or visually analyze some other centered slick slider examples).